# How to quickly jump around windows without entering in tmux choose-tree?

Tags: terminal, tmux

### Steps to reproduce the problem

I run the following commands to create a session with 3 windows.

```
tmux
tmux new-window
tmux new-window
```

I run `tmux choose-tree` or press `Ctrl b w` to show windows.

```
(0) - 0: 3 windows (attached)
(1) ├─> 0: zsh
(2) ├─> 1: zsh-
(3) └─> 2: [tmux]*
```

When I press `2`, tmux enters(chooses) `1: zsh`.

### Expected behavior

In tmux choose-tree, I want to press number keys and make tmux select the corresponding window instead of entering it, as if I click on that window with `set -g mouse on`? For example, I press `2` and tmux selects `1: zsh`, so that I can preview the window and decide whether to enter it.

Comment: @mattb Probably because it's not a programming question and, therefore, off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]

Comment: @Rob fair enough - I guess the OP should have asked this at [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, you have a two options for tackling what you're requesting.

**Option 1: Control key navigation**

By default you can type `Ctrl-b <window-id>` to navigate to the window with the specified id. This bypasses you needing to look at the window tree view before navigating to the window of your choosing.

**Option 2: Alt key navigation** (probably the closest thing to what you want)

Many people add `bind-key -n M-0 select-window -t 0` to their `.tmux.conf` files so when they type `Alt-0` they navigate to the window with an 'id' of 0. You could add a line to your `.tmux.conf` for each numerical navigation so you can `Alt-<id>` to any window.

---

Note, it's likely infeasible to bind simply *just* a number key to window navigation while in `tmux` since it would render that key un-typable.

Comment: Actually, I want to select a window in choose-tree without entering it. My original question might be unclear enough. I modified it to clarify my intention.